# Declaring a subclass in ObjC fails

Tags: objective-c

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I want to put away some methods into separate .h and .m files for a better overview of my code.

So basically I have the `myViewController` which I want to extend with the method `myReactionOnAnimationDidEnd:` **as a category**.

So I declared in `"myCustomClasses.h"` the following to extend it with my desired method:

```
#import "myViewController.h"
@interface myViewController (myReactionOnAnimationDidEnd)
- (void)myReactionOnAnimationDidEnd:(NSNotification *)aNotification;
@end
```

The implementation in `"myCustomClasses.m"` is:

```
#import "myCustomClasses.h"
#import "myViewController.h"

@implementation myViewController (myReactionOnAnimationDidEnd)    
- (void)myReactionOnAnimationDidEnd:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

    self.myLabel1.text = @"Test"; 
}
@end
```

The Compiler throws a build failed error "Cannot find interface declaration for 'myViewController'"

**So here's my questions:**

1. The first weird thing is, that everything works fine if I do exactly the same for UIViewController instead of myViewController. But since myViewController is a subclass of UIViewController, why shouldn't it work for myViewController as well(@interface iSnahViewController : UIViewController)?
2. The other weird thing is that the @implementation in "myCustomClasses.m" works just fine if I skip on the @declaration completely. Now how can that be??

Thank you guys!
Any help much appreciated!!
Hans

---

Now, the funny thing is, that this very same building error comes up even if I create the category with the New File -> ObjC - Category Template. It basically creates the following two files:

in the header file:

```
#import "myViewController.h"

@interface myViewController (myCategories)  //<-- "Cannot find interface declaration for 'myViewController'"



@end
```

and with the .m file

```
#import "myViewController+myCategories.h"

@implementation myViewController (myCategories)


@end
```

And that's already enough to bring up the error from above.

Comment: It's not clear what the relationship is between myViewController and iSnahViewController.  Also, where does the compiler error happen?

Comment: You might want to re-word your question, because you're not creating a subclass, you're creating a category.

Comment: @PhillipMills: I'm sorry, I was a bit careless adjusting the names for a better readability, iSnahViewController is myViewController (I adjusted it in my question)

Comment: @Martin: thank you so much, I indeed wasn't aware of the category concept. Still, when I was talking about subclasses in my question, I was referring to to "myViewController" which is as far as my current understanding goes actually is a subclass of UIViewController.

Comment: Again, what line upsets the compiler?  I just created a category on a subclass of UIViewController using a test project here. It's extremely similar to what you have but gives no error (except I don't import "myViewController.h" in the .m file).

Comment: It's the line `@interface myViewController (myReactionOnAnimationDidEnd)` which throws "Cannot find interface declaration for 'myViewController'". I now even tried leaving out the "myViewController.h" file from the .m file like you said.

Comment: Classes should be capitalized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working!

As the building error occured, I was importing the Category-.h File into the primery Class's .h file:

```
#import "myViewController+myCategories.h" //<-- in the  "myViewController.h"
```

which lead to the building error from above. This seems to be wrong! So don't do that.

I still don't fully understand how the "myViewController" Class gets to know about it's categories without even having their .h files imported, but as this appears to be a working way of how this is done, I wanted to share with you.

Thanks everybody for helping!!

Comment: If you answer your own question, please mark this answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

`myCustomClasses.m` should probably include `myCustomClasses.h` and not `myViewController.h`, so the compiler sees the category declaration. Since `myCustomClasses.h` already includes `myViewController.h`, the compiler should have all necessary declarations.